# Strange memory usage when constructing cell variable

Tags: matlab, memory-leaks

**Edit**  My suspicion is that the RAM usage confusion in the question below is due to MATLAB's "soft-linking" process, where if `y` is N bytes, then doing `x = y` will produce an `x` of size N bytes, but no additional memory is used because the two variables are the same.  But  `x=y+1` will of course require 2*N memory since the variables are now different.
Am I correct in this assumption?

Here is a small function I wrote to process some binary data. My question will follow after I show some results (size of variables).

```
function rawadc = SOexpand(rawdat)
% check for single vector vs. cellstruct
if ~iscell(rawdat),
    rawdat = mat2cell(rawdat,length(rawdat),1);
end
% now cycle thru length of cell var
rawadc = cell(length(rawdat),1);
for jj = 1:length(rawdat) % loop over frames
    tmpin = typecast(rawdat{jj},'uint16');
    tmp123 = bitand(tmpin ,hex2dec('FFF0')) ;
    % reshape so can set up the right order for inserting 4th words
    tmp123 = reshape(tmp123,3,length(tmpin)/3);
    tmp4  = bitshift( bitand(tmpin(1:3:end),hex2dec('000F')),12)...
        + bitshift( bitand(tmpin(2:3:end),hex2dec('000F')),8)...
        + bitshift( bitand(tmpin(3:3:end),hex2dec('000F')),4);
    % reassemble 
    tmpall = [tmp123;tmp4'];
    rawadc{jj} = reshape(tmpall,[numel(tmpall),1]);
end
end % of main
```

My source data is a cell variable:

```
>> whos('datfoo')
  Name           Size                 Bytes  Class    Attributes

  datfoo      1280x1             4026675200  cell
```

If I select a subset of this to process,

```
>> dt(1:100) = datfoo(1:100);
>> medsad = expandSad(dt);
```

and then build a very large cell array with that:

```
>> mot = medsad;
>> for jj = 1:6
mot = [mot;mot];
end
>> whos('mot')
  Name         Size                  Bytes  Class    Attributes

  mot       6400x1             26844262400  cell
```

That's fine, and my RAM usage, per Windows Task Manager, is minimal, i.e. maybe half a Gb or less increase.

But if instead I run the entire source variable thru the function,

```
>> bigmot = SOexpand(datfoo);
>> whos('bigmot')
  Name           Size                 Bytes  Class    Attributes

  bigmot      1280x1             5368852480  cell
```

The class is the same, the size in bytes of `bigmot` is a fraction of that for 'mot' , **but** the RAM usage goes up by nearly 5 Gb !  If I save `bigmot` to a .mat-file and remove it from the workspace, I get the 5Gb back. Reloading from the .mat-file costs me the same 5Gb.  So the question is: what is MATLAB doing here? Why is my function creating a large cell variable costing such a huge memory chunk, despite the reported bytesize? (and why doesn't essentially the same operation at the console do this?)

Please comment if you'd like additional info.   Windows7, MATLAB2015a , i3 quadcore .